# Apply over nested list names: Sub out character in nested list names

Tags: r, list, recursion

I have lists of unknown structure (nesting) that always terminate with a named vector.  I want to substitute all the periods in the list or atomic vector names for an underscore.  There's `rapply` to apply functios to list elements but how do I apply over the list/atomic vector's names?  I am after a base R solution but please share all solutions for others.

### MWE

```
x <- list(
    urban = list(
        cars = c('volvo', 'ford'),
        food.dining = list(
            local.business = c('carls'),
            chain.business = c('dennys', 'panera')
        )
    ),
    rural = list(
        land.use = list(
            farming =list(
                dairy = c('cows'),
                vegie.plan = c('carrots')
            )
        ),
        social.rec = list(
            community.center = c('town.square')
        ),
        people.type = c('good', 'bad', 'in.between')
    ),
    other.locales = c('suburban'),
    missing = list(
        unknown = c(),
        known = c()
    ),
    end = c('wow')
)
```

### Desired Outcome

```
## $urban
## $urban$cars
## [1] "volvo" "ford" 
## 
## $urban$food_dining
## $urban$food_dining$local_business
## [1] "carls"
## 
## $urban$food_dining$chain_business
## [1] "dennys" "panera"
## 
## 
## 
## $rural
## $rural$land_use
## $rural$land_use$farming
## $rural$land_use$farming$dairy
## [1] "cows"
## 
## $rural$land_use$farming$vegie_plan
## [1] "carrots"
## 
## 
## 
## $rural$social_rec
## $rural$social_rec$community_center
## [1] "town.square"
## 
## 
## $rural$people_type
## [1] "good"       "bad"        "in.between"
## 
## 
## $other_locales
## [1] "suburban"
## 
## $missing
## $missing$unknown
## NULL
## 
## $missing$known
## NULL
## 
## 
## $end
## [1] "wow"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea for a recursive function. It first substitutes the periods in the names with underscores. It then checks if the class of an element is `list`, and if yes, it applies the function on that element. Otherwise, if the class is `character`, it substitutes the periods in its elements with underscores. Note that this will not work if there are for example `data.frames` in the list, that would have to be an extension defined in the function as well. Hope this helps!

Function:

```
my_func <- function(x)
{
    names(x) <- gsub('\\.','_',names(x) )
    for(i in 1:length(x))
    {
      if(any(class(x[[i]])=='list'))
      {
        x[[i]] <- my_func(x[[i]])
      }
    }
    return(x)
}
y <- my_func(x)
```

Data:

```
x <- list(
  urban = list(
    cars = c('volvo', 'ford'),
    food.dining = list(
      local.business = c('carls'),
      chain.business = c('dennys', 'panera')
    )
  ),
  rural = list(
    land.use = list(
      farming =list(
        dairy = c('cows'),
        vegie.plan = c('carrots')
      )
    ),
    social.rec = list(
      community.center = c('town.square')
    ),
    people.type = c('good', 'bad', 'in.between')
  ),
  other.locales = c('suburban'),
  missing = list(
    unknown = c(),
    known = c()
  ),
  end = c('wow')
)
```

Output:

```
 str(y)

List of 5
 $ urban        :List of 2
  ..$ cars       : chr [1:2] "volvo" "ford"
  ..$ food_dining:List of 2
  .. ..$ local_business: chr "carls"
  .. ..$ chain_business: chr [1:2] "dennys" "panera"
 $ rural        :List of 3
  ..$ land_use   :List of 1
  .. ..$ farming:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ dairy     : chr "cows"
  .. .. ..$ vegie_plan: chr "carrots"
  ..$ social_rec :List of 1
  .. ..$ community_center: chr "town.square"
  ..$ people_type: chr [1:3] "good" "bad" "in.between"
 $ other_locales: chr "suburban"
 $ missing      :List of 2
  ..$ unknown: NULL
  ..$ known  : NULL
 $ end          : chr "wow"
```

Answer (score 4):

For `list` objects, it will rename the `list` and recursively call the same function for each of its elements. For `character` objects, it will just return the `character`.

```
library('purrr')

fix_names.list <- function(v) {
  names(v) <- gsub('\\.', '_', names(v))
  map(v, fix_names)
}

fix_names.default <- function(v) v

fix_names <- function(v) UseMethod('fix_names')

fix_names(x) %>% str
 # List of 5
 # $ urban        :List of 2
 #  ..$ cars       : chr [1:2] "volvo" "ford"
 #  ..$ food_dining:List of 2
 #  .. ..$ local_business: chr "carls"
 #  .. ..$ chain_business: chr [1:2] "dennys" "panera"
 # $ rural        :List of 3
 #  ..$ land_use   :List of 1
 #  .. ..$ farming:List of 2
 #  .. .. ..$ dairy     : chr "cows"
 #  .. .. ..$ vegie_plan: chr "carrots"
 #  ..$ social_rec :List of 1
 #  .. ..$ community_center: chr "town.square"
 #  ..$ people_type: chr [1:3] "good" "bad" "in.between"
 # $ other_locales: chr "suburban"
 # $ missing      :List of 2
 #  ..$ unknown: NULL
 #  ..$ known  : NULL
 # $ end          : chr "wow"
```

Comment: `map` is from the `purrr`-package; not from `tidyverse`

Comment: Note that `map` could be repalced with `lapply` for a pure base solution (I believe)

Answer (score 1):

Not a base-R approach, but might still be relevant as this can be done out-of-the-box with `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (an extension of base-`rapply`):

```r
x1 <- rrapply::rrapply(
  x,                                                  ## nested list
  f = function(x, .xname) gsub("\\.", "_", .xname),   ## new names
  how = "names"                                       ## replace names instead of content
)

str(x1)
#> List of 5
#>  $ urban        :List of 2
#>   ..$ cars       : chr [1:2] "volvo" "ford"
#>   ..$ food_dining:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ local_business: chr "carls"
#>   .. ..$ chain_business: chr [1:2] "dennys" "panera"
#>  $ rural        :List of 3
#>   ..$ land_use   :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ farming:List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ dairy     : chr "cows"
#>   .. .. ..$ vegie_plan: chr "carrots"
#>   ..$ social_rec :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ community_center: chr "town.square"
#>   ..$ people_type: chr [1:3] "good" "bad" "in.between"
#>  $ other_locales: chr "suburban"
#>  $ missing      :List of 2
#>   ..$ unknown: NULL
#>   ..$ known  : NULL
#>  $ end          : chr "wow"
```